# Limiting conditional comment to home only in header.php

Tags: wp-blog-header.php

I've discovered a solution to an IE problem with a conditional comment. I only need it on the home page because I've isolated there with a class on only one image. Unfortunately, the comment causes me some problems on other pages so I need to limit the comment (and script) to function ONLY on the home page... here's what my comment looks like but it's not preventing from the other pages... I'm more designer than php guy but I'm trying...

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><?php if(is_home() )?> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/unitpngfix.js"></script>
```

Would certainly appreciate any help with this. Thanks much...

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

There are likely more elegant ways to do this sort of thing, but the quickest and easiest, using your code, would be to move the PHP conditional out of the CSS conditional. e.g. change this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><?php if(is_home() )?> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/unitpngfix.js"></script>
```

...to this:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) { ?> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/unitpngfix.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Also: aren't you missing the closing of the CSS conditional here?

```
<?php if( is_home() ) { ?> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/unitpngfix.js"></script>
    -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Resolved! Very appreciative! ~Jeff

Comment: Sorry, messed up my comments, but Chip, you were right, the close also needed to be in there. Thanks again.